# Print all possible diameters of Binary Tree?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

I know how to calculate the [diameter](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diameter-of-a-binary-tree/) of tree but I want to print all possible diameters of tree. Taking the below example:-

```
        1
       / \
      2   3
     /   / \
    4   5   6
```

All Possible diameters in above tree are:-

```
First:  4 2 1 3 5
Second: 4 2 1 3 6
```

Any help regarding approach will very helpful.

Comment: Given diameter is a single number for a given tree, what do you mean by all possible diameters?

Comment: You got diameter 5 because the actual diameter is 5.

Comment: Never heard of a tree (data structure) having a diameter. 5 is the depth of the tree. I'd probably try a path finding algorithm

Comment: No, depth would be 3 here

Comment: @weston I mean print the all nodes in That diameters!!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean all possible paths of maximal length from one leaf to another?

Recursion may be your best bet - in pseudocode something like:

```
path(startNode, endNode) {
  if startNode = endNode return;
  for each possible next node n {
    add n to your path;
    path(n, endNode);
  }
}
```

You could call this for each pair of leaves then throwaway any non-maximal length paths, or perhaps choose which leaves to call this on in a bit more of a smart way, which I would leave up to you

Comment: How to find the start node & end node... Because We know only root of tree.

Answer (score 0):

How is this done in graphs:

1. Run BFS from any node n to find most distant node (from that node) n'
2. Run BFS from node n' to his most distant node n''
3. The path from n' to n'' is the tree diameter

So, looking at a tree (which can be unrolled into a graph):

A diameter path goes from any leaf on the lowest level in the left sub-tree to any leaf on the lowest level in the right sub-tree.

Now, since you don't don't magically know which 2 nodes are the end nodes of a diameter, and you only have parent-to-child links, the above algorithm wont work, per se. However, you can use the analogy to build one that works on trees instead of graphs.

OK, here is some quick code you can use (it may not be optimal, but it works)

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
    ...

    public Iterable<T> diameter() {
        if (this.root == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Deque<T> diameterLeftPart = new ArrayDeque<T>();
        Deque<T> diameterRightPart = new ArrayDeque<T>();

        diameter(this.root.left, diameterLeftPart);
        diameter(this.root.right, diameterRightPart);

        Deque<T> diameter = new ArrayDeque<T>();

        for (Iterator<T> it = diameterLeftPart.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            diameter.offerLast(it.next());
        }

        diameter.offerLast(this.root.item);

        for (Iterator<T> it = diameterRightPart.descendingIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            diameter.offerLast(it.next());
        }

        return diameter;
    }

    private void diameter(Node node, Deque<T> diameter) {
        if (node == null)  {
            return;
        }

        Deque<T> leftPart = new ArrayDeque<T>();
        Deque<T> rightPart = new ArrayDeque<T>();

        diameter(node.left, leftPart);
        diameter(node.right, rightPart);

        if (leftPart.size() > rightPart.size()) {
            diameter.addAll(leftPart);
        } else {
            diameter.addAll(rightPart);
        }

        diameter.offerLast(node.item);
    }

    ...
}
```

And the runner class:

```
public class TreeDiameter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tree<Integer> tree = new BinarySearchTree<Integer>();
        tree.add(5);
        tree.add(2);
        tree.add(8);
        tree.add(1);
        tree.add(3);
        tree.add(7);
        tree.add(9);
        tree.add(4);
        tree.add(6);

        for (Integer diameterNode : tree.diameter()) {
            System.out.print(diameterNode + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

With the following output:

```
4 3 2 5 8 7 6
```

Quick explanation:

We know that the root is the integral part of the diameter path.
So, we want to get the longest path in the left sub-tree and the longest path in the right sub-tree.
Glued together, they create a diameter.

Using recursive calls `diameter(node.left, leftPart)` and `diameter(node.right, rightPart)`, `leftPart` and `rightPart` contain longest paths in left and right sub-trees, respectively.

Simply comparing their sizes gives us the indication which one we will use in constructing the diameter for one level up the tree.

So, to sum up:
Recursion first goes all the way down to the tree and returns the longest path in that sub-tree, passing it upwards to its parent, all the way up to the root.

Comment: First Its Not home work. And what is distant means here. I think you are talking about deepest node here?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Current version will only return 1 diameter, but it can give you some insight on how to move along the tree :D

Comment: As I sad in the previous comment, it only returns 1 of the N possible longest diameters (but always the longest one)

Comment: Diameter is the largest path in tree. It can be more then one but should be of equal length.!!! In code , how are you calculating diameter!!!